# How to save files in a loop to xlsm macro enabled format?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that loops through files and saves them as new files.

```
Sub ImportWorksheets()
   '=============================================
   'Process all Excel files in specified folder
   '=============================================
   Dim sFile As String           'file to process
   Dim wbTarget As Workbook
   Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
   Dim wsHide1 As Worksheet 'Declare Sheets to hide'
   Dim wsHide2 As Worksheet
   Dim wsHide3 As Worksheet
   Dim wsHide4 As Worksheet
   Dim wbSource As Workbook
   Dim wsSource As Worksheet
   Dim rowTarget As Long 'output row

   'Master workbook row that needs to be updated with source data'
   rowTarget = 9
   
   'Source files location'
   Const FOLDER_PATH = "T:\SAMPLE DATA\1 - Split Raw Files\"

   'loop through the Excel files in the folder'
  sFile = Dir(FOLDER_PATH & "*.xls*")
  
'open template'
    Const MASTER = "T:\SAMPLE DATA\ V7 Template\Tool Template V7.xlsm"
    Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(MASTER)
   
    Set wsTarget = Sheets("DATABASE") 'Target sheet of where data from source needs to be inserted'
    
    'Sheets to hide'
    Set wsHide1 = Sheets("Office Use Only1")
    Set wsHide2 = Sheets("Office Use Only2")
    Set wsHide3 = Sheets("Office Use Only3")
    Set wsHide4 = Sheets("Office Use Only4")
    
         wsTarget.Visible = xlVeryHidden
         wsHide1.Visible = xlVeryHidden
         wsHide2.Visible = xlVeryHidden
         wsHide3.Visible = xlVeryHidden
         wsHide4.Visible = xlVeryHidden

    Do While sFile <> ""
    
        ' read source
        Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(FOLDER_PATH & sFile) ' update links, readonly
        Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets(1)
          
        ' create target'
        'wsTarget.Name = Replace(sFile, ".xlsx", "")'
        wsTarget.Name = "DATABASE"
        wsTarget.Unprotect "Password"
        wsTarget.Range("A" & rowTarget).Resize(1, 364) = wsSource.Range("A2:MZ2").Value
        wbTarget.SaveAs "T:\SAMPLE DATA\2 -Final  Files\" & sFile & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, _
        CreateBackup:=False
        wsTarget.Protect "Password"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Remove pop up messages'
        wbSource.Close False
    
        sFile = Dir
         wsTarget.Visible = xlVeryHidden
         wsHide1.Visible = xlVeryHidden
         wsHide2.Visible = xlVeryHidden
         wsHide3.Visible = xlVeryHidden
         wsHide4.Visible = xlVeryHidden
    Loop
    wbTarget.Close False

End Sub
```

However the files keep saving as xlsx files in the loop and not macro enabled files with xlsm format. I also see that the files are saved with this type "Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet".. This format is supposed to be Microsoft macro enabled workbook as i use FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled.
[image]

Also how do i remove this pop up when i try to open the generated files above ? I tried to use Application.DisplayAlerts = False. However this doesn't seem to work.
[image]

Comment: Would you kindly add the code as text by using copy/paste and then select it and use `CTRL+K` to format it or let someone else do so? Use the `Edit` button below your post.

Comment: As above, please edit your question to include your code as text, not as an image - However, I had a similar issue once before and I think to fix it I included `.xlsm` at the end of the new file name.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for commenting. I have saved the code as text.

Comment: @SamuelEverson Would i need to remove the fileformat portion and just include '.xlsm' after sFile ?

Comment: Replace the extension in sFile with '.xlsm'.

Comment: Could you share the complete relevant code? We can't see the value of `sFile` which is crucial in answering your question. Also unticking `Hide extensions for known file types` in `Windows FileExplorer>View>Options>View` may be beneficial. You're not a computer beginner anymore.

Comment: Hi All, Apologies. I have reuploaded the correct information as mentioned. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Save File in Another Format

- When changing the format of a file, you have to change both, its extension and the `FileFormat` parameter.
- Also, note that column `MZ` is column `364`, not `347`.

```vb
Dim NewName As String
NewName = "T:\SAMPLE DATA\2 - Files\" & "test- " & sFile
NewName = Left(NewName, InStrRev(NewName, ".")) & "xlsm"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Remove pop up messages'
wbTarget.SaveAs NewName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, _
    CreateBackup:=False
wsTarget.Protect "Password"
wbSource.Close False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Thanks @VBasic2008 for your assistance. I have reuploaded my entire code which  shows you how sFile is created. Kindly view above. Thank you very much :)